# Jquery call function on hover if element is of class A but not class B

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to call a function when hovering over elements with a specific class attribute, but not another. I feel like the `:not` selector should work, but it is still firing for all elements of class A.

I have elements with a specific class `.sidebar-section`, but one of them has another class attribute `.show`, I want to call a function on hover for class `sidebar-section` excluding elements that are also of the class `show`.

```
    <div class="sidebar-section show" id="one">
        <div class="sidebar-title">Ones</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-section" id="two">
        <div class="sidebar-title">Twos</div>
    </div>
```

I want to set up a hover listener for `sidebar-section` that will fire when hovering over `Twos` but not over `Ones`. I have tried `$(".sidebar-section:not(.show)").hover()` but for some reason this is not working, since it still fires for all `sidebar-sections`.

```
$(".sidebar-section:not(.show)").hover(
    function () {
        toggleSection(this.id);
    },
    function () {
        toggleSection(this.id);
    }
);
```

Thanks to @CBroe's suggestion I've edited the code by moving the check for the `show` class into hover handler. This accomplished the main part of my question since the shown element no longer collapses when hovered over. But this collapses the element when I leave.

To fix this I added a mouseleave event handler with a function to toggle `#one` once the mouse is no longer on the sidebar, but the function is never called. Why is the mouseleave of the `sidebar-container` not executing?

```js
//Contents are hidden unless section is selected
$(function () {
    $(".sidebar-contents").hide();
    toggleSection("one");
});

$(".sidebar-section").hover(
    function () {
        if(!$(this).hasClass("show")){
            toggleSection(this.id);
        }
    },
    function () {
        toggleSection(this.id);
    }
);

$("#sidebar-container").mouseleave(
    function () {
        toggleSection("one");
    }
);

//toggles collapsed/expanded view of sidebar sections
function toggleSection(name) {
    $("#" + name).children('.sidebar-contents').toggle();
    $("#" + name).children('.sidebar-title').toggle();
    $("#" + name).toggleClass('show');
}
```

```css
#sidebar-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar-section {
    background-color: blue;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

.sidebar-section.show {
    background-color: yellow;
    writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar-container">
    <div class="sidebar-section" id="one">
        <div class="sidebar-title">Ones</div>
        <ul class="sidebar-contents">
            <li>Item 1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-section" id="two">
        <div class="sidebar-title">Twos</div>
        <ul class="sidebar-contents">
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please edit your question and include the (relevant) parts of your code here on SO.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a couple code blocks with what I hope is enough code to provide context for my question.

Comment: Since you have assigned `id` to each item, why don't you use `id` selector instead of `class`?

Comment: Hi, if you make your codeply into a working StackOverflow snippet you are more likely to get help as it's easier for us to see what is going on (and in future the code won't get lost).

Comment: I am not sure why your selector isn't working, but in jQuery [you can also use](https://api.jquery.com/not/) `$(".sidebar-section").not(".show")`.

Comment: @Shuvo The id is different for each element, and the hover functionality should work for all ```sidebar-section``` elements that are not of class ```show```  

@Don't Panic I have also tried the ```.not()``` as a function, with the same results as the ```:not``` selector.

Comment: `$(".sidebar-section:not(.show)").hover()` binds the event handler to the elements that exist at the time this line executes. You however appear to be toggling that `show` class later on - that won’t work. All elements that did not have that class the time this line executed, will have the handler function bound to them. You need another approach - check whether the element the event is occurring on has that class or not, from _inside_ the handler function. Or maybe event delegation.

Comment: @CBroe Oh, right. I always forget changed elements won't be bound to my handlers.

Comment: What @CBroe said. See [Direct and delegated event handlers](https://api.jquery.com/on/), maybe try something like `$(".sidebar-contents").on("hover", ":not(.show)", function() { ... })`? Or just move the filter into the handler, like `if ($(this).hasClass('show') ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `toggleSection` function. When you `hover` over an item, you are toggling the `show` class. That is why, your selector doesn't work. Can you update your `hover` function with this:

```
$(".sidebar-section").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).children('.sidebar-contents').show();
        $(this).children('.sidebar-title').hide();
        $(this).addClass('show');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).children('.sidebar-contents').hide();
        $(this).children('.sidebar-title').show();
        $(this).removeClass('show');
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. It essentially accomplishes the same as @CBroe's suggestion. The reason for putting the toggling in another function was to allow ```sidebar-sections``` to be expanded from elsewhere in code via a function call.